# How to find matching coins in a row?

Tags: php, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I want to find matching coin faces in a row. I managed to make it so that 3 matching tails in a row will end the loop.

But how can I include heads (it seems to ignore heads)?

For example:

```
0 is heads 
reset 
0 is heads 
reset 
1 is tails 
1 is tails 
1 is tails 
total flips took is: 5
```

PHP:

```
$flipCounts = 0;
$matchingFaceTypes = 0;

$targetReached = false;
while ($matchingFaceTypes < 3 ) { 
    $faceType = rand(0, 1); 
    $flipCounts++; 
    if($faceType == 0) { 
        $matchingFaceTypes++;
        echo $faceType . " is heads ". "\n";
        }
    if($faceType == 1) {

        $matchingFaceTypes++;
        echo $faceType." is tails ". "\n";

    } else {
            $matchingFaceTypes =0;
            echo " reset ". "\n";
        }
    } echo "total flips took is: " . $flipCounts;
```

Comment: You are setting `$matchingFaceTypes =0;` any time that `$faceType == 1` is false. What you want to do is keep track of what the previous type was, and then reset if the current type is not the same as the previous type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$maxMatches = 3;
$matches = array('tails' => 0, 'heads' => 0, 'total' => 0);

while(max($matches['tails'], $matches['heads']) < $maxMatches) { 
    $faceType = rand(0, 1); 
    if ($faceType) { 
       $matches['heads']++;
       $matches['tails'] = 0;
       echo $faceType . " is heads\n";
    }
    else {
       $matches['tails']++;
       $matches['heads'] = 0;
       echo $faceType . " is tails\n";
    }
    $matches['total']++;
}

echo "total flips took is: " . $matches['total'];
```

Speaking of max()

```
$maxMatches = 3;
$total = 0;
$matches = array('tails' => 0, 'heads' => 0);

while(max($matches) < $maxMatches) { 
    $faceType = rand(0, 1); 
    if ($faceType) { 
       $matches['heads']++;
       $matches['tails'] = 0;
       echo $faceType . " is heads\n";
    }
    else {
       $matches['tails']++;
       $matches['heads'] = 0;
       echo $faceType . " is tails\n";
    }
    $total++;
}

echo "total flips took is: " . $total;
```

Comment: This works, thanks. I want to ask, is it necessary to use max in the while parameter?

Comment: @Martynogea You can check each element `heads` and `tails` separately.  My way is just slightly shorter. If you move `total` to a separate variable then you can do just `max($matches) < $maxMatches`

Comment: @Martynogea I wrote another example, where `max()` is useful.

Comment: ahhhh IMO I think the second one with the additional variable is easier to grasp. PS: Just did char count and second one has overall 437 chars whereas the other one you said shorter has 489 chars. But I understand wher you're coming from by saying it's shorter.

Comment: @Martynogea Shorter does not mean 'less number of chars'. I can use one letter variables, write everything in one row and so on to make it 'shorter'. I meant easier way to read and understand the code.

Answer (score 1):

The else refers to the second if, so the else will be taken if $facetype==0

Next problem: you are not checking if the last type is like the one before

I'd recommend a variable called `$lasttype` and check if `$faceType` equals that, if not reset the counter and after that do the output

```
$flipCounts = 0;
$matchingFaceTypes = 0;
$ctype=0;
$targetReached = false;
$lasttype=-1;

while ($matchingFaceTypes < 3 ) { 
    $faceType = rand(0, 1); 
    $flipCounts++; 
    if($faceType != $lasttype) {
        if($lasttype!=-1)
            echo " reset ". "\n<br/>";
        $lasttype=$faceType;
        $matchingFaceTypes =0;
    }

    if($faceType == 0) { 
        $matchingFaceTypes++;
        echo $faceType . " is heads ". "\n<br/>";
    }else{
        $matchingFaceTypes++;
        echo $faceType." is tails ". "\n<br/>";
    }    
} 
echo "total flips took is: " . $flipCounts;
```

Comment: This works thanks. But I'm confused on why last type equals to -1. Is it just a random number?

Comment: the -1 is the initial value and will never occur again, so it won't say reset right in the beginning

Comment: I tested with -5, and the code still works. I also deleted the second if statement too, still works. I even made the $lasttype variable on its own, not equal to anything. Still works. I don't actually get why it's working fine though. As long as $lasttype=$facetType; is there, the code works.

Comment: you could also cange the value to any value(even null or something like that) as long as you change it in both places(defining and checking)... 

If you don't do it in both places, sure it will work, but the first output would be "reset"

Right now i'm saying lasttype is -1 before the first roll and at all rolls i check if this var is still -1, cause then I know it's the first roll, and by that i supress the first "reset"